# where is the text / description for substrate democracy pallets propose

Tags: substrate-node-template

where is the actual text/description for the democracy pallet propose function
this is the function I am talking about https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/4d598040e0369b02cd24e8e67eaf317d09f74f85/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L629
is the proposal_hash parameter the hash of the content / description of the change being proposed? if so , where is the actual content stored? could it be IPFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you propose the proposal, you need to [submit a preimage](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/4d598040e0369b02cd24e8e67eaf317d09f74f85/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L1001).

And the data was [stored on the chain](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/4d598040e0369b02cd24e8e67eaf317d09f74f85/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L1891).

It could be IPFS (in some ways). You could upload your proposal content to IPFS, then use the link as the preimage data.

Comment: thanks much clearer